# clipboard in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I was searching for how to implement clipboard in silverlight.

I used this link for designing clipboard.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/clipboard-access/

But it shows error on this line:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Alert(HostNoClipboard);
```

and

```
(ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("clipboardData");
```

throws `null` always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/accessing-global-clipboard/

Answer (score 0):

follow the link provided below

[Clipboard Support in Silverlight](http://silverlightips.net/2010/09/15/clipboard-copy-paste-silverlight/)